# Every grep command returns "grep: invalid option -- '='"

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I've already removed and reinstalled `grep` on Ubuntu but still the same error persists.

Whatever grep` command I type I always see the following output:

```
grep: invalid option -- '='
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try grep --help for more information.`
```

So even

```
grep -V
```

results in this error, or

```
grep --help
```

same thing!

`/bin/grep` has the same byte size as it does on my other identical hosts, where it works fine, so it's likely to be some environmental variable or local setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: I honestly cannot tell you why, but going in and out of the bash shell a couple of times, and it's working perfectly - I'd still be interested in ideas as to why this occurred. other commands remained unaffected.

Comment: probably you had an alias like `grep -=`. I'd suggest you to mark Jeremy's answer as the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 25):

In case this isn't yet fixed, see if there is any file in the directory that starts with a '-'.

Reference: [Stephane Chazelas' answer here](https://comp.unix.shell.narkive.com/wGDYtwDV/grep-invalid-option) [EDIT: updated old link to a new working reference]

Helped me.

Comment: That was it for me! Pretty much a problem for any command that has a glob in it I guess.

Comment: the reference link doesn't work (site under construction)

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you have an alias to grep, which is adding invalid arguments. Try the following:

```
type grep
```

this will tell you if the `grep` command is an alias or not. If it is, check your `.profile`, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files for where this alias is defined.

Comment: thanks, yeah I tried this, using the command `alias` too. I am sure this was part of the answer as I noticed that there were no aliases defined on the box, whereas there should have been a few (as this box is identical to some other boxes which show their alias list correctly)

I should add that the problem is no longer there, when I execute the command

`type grep`

I do get the correct alias of 

`grep is aliased to \`grep --color=auto'`

 which of course is just allowing me to see things in colour for tired eyes :)

Comment: So you're saying that it's working fine now? Did you change anything?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use:

```
grep -e "="
```

Comment: If the command `grep --help` gives the invalid option error, then this is not an answer.

Comment: This helped me, I ended up here trying to grep search a string that contained -> which gave error "grep invalid option -- >".  I added -e to my command to tell grep that the next argument is a pattern and not an argument.

Comment: Helped me as well. Same thing: I need to look for method invocation (`->`) very often but kept getting the error. The `-e` flag was the solution. Thanks for elaborating @zeros-and-ones

Answer (score 4):

its because there's a file in the directory starting with -

example 1:

```
touch ./-mike.txt

ls

-mike.txt

grep -i blah *

grep: invalid max count
```

example 2:

```
touch ./-sike.txt

grep -i blah *

grep: invalid option -- 'k'

Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

solution remove files starting with - , example:

```
rm ./-sike.txt
```

Comment: You can also type `grep -i blah -- *` The two dashes tell `grep` that the options are over now and everything after them is actually a filename. Many programs accept these two dashes to indicate _end-of-options_. This way you don't need to delete your files just because `grep` cannot handle them ;-)